# Can't print jpg with Aspose.Pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, jpeg, aspose.pdf

I want to load in a JPEG file and print it with Aspose.Pdf in C# (.net Framework 4.8). The code I currently have is:

```
public void PrintImage(string fileToPrint, string printerName, string jobName)
    {
      System.Drawing.Image srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileToPrint);
      int h = srcImage.Height;
      int w = srcImage.Width;

      var doc = new Document();
      var page = doc.Pages.Add();
      var image = new Image();
      image.File = (fileToPrint);

      page.PageInfo.Height = (h);
      page.PageInfo.Width = (w);
      page.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = (0);
      page.PageInfo.Margin.Top = (0);
      page.PageInfo.Margin.Right = (0);
      page.PageInfo.Margin.Left = (0);

      page.Paragraphs.Add(image);

      var viewer = new PdfViewer(doc);
      PrintUsingViewer(viewer, printerName, jobName);
    }

    private static void PrintUsingViewer(PdfViewer viewer, string printerName, string jobName)
    {
      viewer.AutoResize = true;         // Print the file with adjusted size
      viewer.AutoRotate = true;         // Print the file with adjusted rotation
      viewer.PrintPageDialog = false;   // Do not produce the page number dialog when printing

      var ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
      var pgs = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();

      ps.PrinterName = printerName;
      viewer.PrinterJobName = jobName;

      viewer.PrintDocumentWithSettings(pgs, ps);
      viewer.Close();
    }
```

When I save the document instead of printing and look at it, it seems fine (the image is added). However, when trying to print the image it is not printed and the page is just blank..

I would like to print without first saving the document as a PDF and then trying to print that saved PDF. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: After page.Paragraphs.Add(image); line, please try to add doc.ProcessParagraphs(); and then print the file. If the problem still persists, please let us know by creating a post in our official support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf/10) as it is the right place to discuss such issues so that they can be properly addressed and resolved. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: This resolved the issue! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding this line of code

```
doc.ProcessParagraphs();
```

right after this line:

```
page.Paragraphs.Add(image);
```

So the code now becomes

```
public void PrintImage(string fileToPrint, string printerName, string jobName)
    {
      System.Drawing.Image srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileToPrint);
      int h = srcImage.Height;
      int w = srcImage.Width;

      var doc = new Document();
      var page = doc.Pages.Add();
      var image = new Image();
      image.File = (fileToPrint);

      page.PageInfo.Height = (h);
      page.PageInfo.Width = (w);
      page.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = (0);
      page.PageInfo.Margin.Top = (0);
      page.PageInfo.Margin.Right = (0);
      page.PageInfo.Margin.Left = (0);

      page.Paragraphs.Add(image);
      doc.ProcessParagraphs();

      var viewer = new PdfViewer(doc);
      PrintUsingViewer(viewer, printerName, jobName);
    }

    private static void PrintUsingViewer(PdfViewer viewer, string printerName, string jobName)
    {
      viewer.AutoResize = true;         // Print the file with adjusted size
      viewer.AutoRotate = true;         // Print the file with adjusted rotation
      viewer.PrintPageDialog = false;   // Do not produce the page number dialog when printing

      var ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
      var pgs = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();

      ps.PrinterName = printerName;
      viewer.PrinterJobName = jobName;

      viewer.PrintDocumentWithSettings(pgs, ps);
      viewer.Close();
    }
```

Now the image is printed correctly!